# Codeigniter + Autocomplete JQuery UI não retorna lista

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-ui

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu tenho um campo de pesquisa onde eu dou "sugestões" do que digitar, baseado no que possuo cadastrado no meu banco de dados. O mesmo estava funcionando perfeitamente, porém parou de funcionar e não consigo achar o erro.

**Script:**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#query').autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo site_url('artigos/sugestao'); ?>"
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function sugestao()
{
    if(esta_logado() == TRUE){
        if(isset($_GET['term'])){
            $result = $this->artigos->sugestao($_GET['term']);
            if(count($result) > 0){
                foreach ($result as $r)
                    $arr_result[] = $r->titulo;
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    } else {
        redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function sugestao($palavraChave)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("//select que utilizo");
    return $query->result();
}
```

se eu testar chamar desta forma no navegador http://localhost/artigos/sugestao?term=**PalavraQualquer** ele me retorna o resultado normalmente, porém no momento que digito no input ele não mostra a listagem como era feito antes.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que usar *AJAX* pra fazer isso, como você está usando `$_GET` pra fazer a busca você vai ser necessáruio usar [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
jQuery("#query").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        jQuery.get("<?php echo site_url('artigos/sugestao'); ?>", {
            term: request.term
        }, function (data) {
            response(data);
        });
    },
    minLength: 3 // define o número mínimo de caracteres digitados antes de fazer a busca
});
```

Comment: não funcionou desta forma :/

Comment: Poderia dizer o que acontece? Assim podemos ver se uma lolução melhor

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda... com este código que me passou ele nem trás resultados, quando testo digitar algo ele não me joga nada no console do Chrome, com o que está ele me tras a requisição no console e se eu acessar a URL que ele cria ele me retorna os resultados ele só não exibe abaixo do input estes resultados.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Entendi irei fazer uns testes

Answer (score 0):

**David**, vi que está usando o [`autocomplete`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Se o resultado proposto é trazido via browser, o problema está no JQuery.

Verifique:

- Se o console do inspetor de elementos do Chrome exibe algum erro (Chrome > F12)
- Se o campo com id `#query` existe
- Se o caminho trazido por `<?php echo site_url('artigos/sugestao'); ?>` é válido (exiba o código fonte na página e veja a URL expressa explicitamente), pois de repente você modificou algo e não se lembra ou mesmo um simples `.htaccess` pode ter estragado a brincadeira.

Você também pode executar manualmente no console do inspetor de elementos (F12) do Chrome a requisição (basta colar e dar ENTER):

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
    source: "URL_COMPLETA_AQUI"
});
```

Deste modo é possível ver o retorno ou erro que o JQUERY possa estourar.

Comment: Verifiquei no console do Chrome e não retorna nenhum erro. O campo query existe e o <?php echo site_url('artigos/sugestao'); ?> retorna a url normalmente, também tentei passar a url completa e nada. Como expliquei antes estava funcionando e não lembro de ter modificado nada que afetasse isto.